# Regex for matching dates

Tags: xml, regex

How can I find the validity start- and enddate  with a regular expression from this piece of xml?

```
<Response>
  <Identification v="XXXXX"/>
  <Type v="YYY"/>
  <CreationDateTime v="2013-01-18T10:00:00Z"/>
  <ValidityPeriod v="2013-01-21T05:00Z/2013-01-22T05:00Z"/>
 <The rest of the file i'm not iterested in..../>
```

So far I found  **[1-9][0-9]{3}-.+?T.+?Z/.+?Z**  to find the value of the attribute and split the string in two date strings.
Or use **[1-9][0-9]{3}-.+?T[^.]+?(Z|[+-].+)** and find three dates and only use the last two

But how do I find exact two matches with two separate dates.

I have to extract some xml files from an archive (with a lot and large XML files) and for performance reasons I can't deserialize all the files.

Comment: Any reason why you don't use the text like ValidityPeriod for your regexp?

Comment: No no particular reason I was focused on the dates but it appeared I only needed the validity.

Answer (score 1):

Use [JDOM](http://www.jdom.org/) or another XML parsing language instead of regular expressions. It will simplify parsing this text. Alternatively, you know that the element is named "CreationDateTime", you know that the attribute is named "v", and you know that the value is enclosed within double quotes. You can use all of that information to your advantage to parse it using String splitting to more easily get the lines and values you're interested in.

Comment: Not always full featured XML parsing is the best solution. Sometimes a small regexp is much faster and easier than to setup an XML parser and care for all the special cases (e.g. ill-formed XML).

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
my $d = qr([1-9][0-9]{3}-.+?T.+?Z);
my ($d1, $d2) = ($xml =~ /ValidityPeriod v=\"($d)\/($d)\"/);
print "$d1 $d2\n" if $d1;
```

The $d regexp can be as complicated as you want. ".*" would be enough :-)